# How to fix this foreach function error with nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase

I have a nodejs script allowing me to insert data contained in json files on Firestore, but after execution I have a function not found error.
How can I fix this situation?
Thanks
Here is all my code:

```
var admin = require("firebase-admin");

var serviceAccount = require("./service_key.json");

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://xxxxxxxxx.firebaseio.com"
});

const firestore = admin.firestore();
const path = require("path");
const fs = require("fs");
const directoryPath = path.join(__dirname, "files");

fs.readdir(directoryPath, function(err, files) {
  if (err) {
    return console.log("Unable to scan directory: " + err);
  }

  files.forEach(function(file) {
    var lastDotIndex = file.lastIndexOf(".");

    var menu = require("./files/" + file);

    menu.forEach(function(obj) {
      firestore
        .collection(file.substring(0, lastDotIndex))
        .doc(obj.itemID)
        .set(obj)
        .then(function(docRef) {
          console.log("Document written");
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
        });
    });
  });
});
```

I have this mistake to send back:

```
/Users/nana/Documents/SCRIPT/uploader.js:25
    menu.forEach(function(obj) {
         ^

TypeError: menu.forEach is not a function
    at /Users/nana/Documents/SCRIPT/uploader.js:25:10
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at /Users/nana/Documents/SCRIPT/uploader.js:20:9
    at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:188:23)
```

Comment: could you share what contain menu variable ?

Comment: You're new here. You need to provide us with a list of the things you tried so that we don't just give you the obvious answers -- which you may have already tried. Try googling "forEach is not a function".

Comment: I don't know anything about nodejs, it's just a script I got on the net to help me to use a Realtime database on Firestore

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell `menu` isn't an array. You are simply `requiring` a file inside the path of `'./files/'`.

Try `console.log(typeof menu)` to see what the terminal says menu is. But to me it doesn't look like an array.

Comment: the console makes it clear that it is an `object

Comment: That is what I figured. An `object` isn't an array. You could use `Object.entries(menu)` or you could use a `for...in` or `for...of` loop instead, those are meant for objects.

Comment: If you can provide a more detailed explanation of what you are trying to achieve I can try to help you more.

Comment: What I want is to take the export file of the Realtime database which is on json and then insert this content in Firebase Firestore.

Comment: So do you need the json to stay json? What format do you need it in?

Comment: I want it to be sent in json

Comment: Is there anyway you can provide all of your code? I have never used firebase, so I can't really help unless I can see it all. 

Because if you are trying to send something that is already json, I am not sure why you are trying to read the file contents.

Unless your realtime db's json object doesn't match how you need to send it into firebase. 

In which case you need to parse the JSON object from the realtime db using `JSON.parse` format it the way you need then, convert it back to JSON using `JSON.stringify`

But, I have never deal with firebase. So I don't know anything about it.